# Android Services: to get the effects of the changes made by the service

Tags: android, service, android-manifest, android-service, android-location

I have a service that sets Latitude and Longitude value(By method:Location.setLongitude.....) at some time difference(Gets the Lat Long value from a text file).
Can I get the Lat Long value in the Activity
a) Which is in the same application.
b) Which is in some other application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a bound Service, you will be able to implements the Listener interface within that Service, subscribe your Activity to the Service's listeners list and whenever you find new data you'll notify the whole list. It's not hard to implement, and if you're in that case I can provide you some code help.

If you use a started service, just send some Intents from your Service and previously register a BroadcastListener in your Activity. You'll just have to put some extras into your Intent and your Activity will recover them.

Using the Intent and the BroadcastReceiver method, you'll be able to perform data transfer between 2 applications (using custom action type and intent-filter).